# How to populate dropdown list for specific user?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have three dropdown list:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Edit.SelectCountryId, Model.Edit.Countries, "Please select", new { id = "CountryID", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "LoadRegions();" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Edit.SelectRegionId,Model.Edit.Region, "Please select", new { id = "RegionID", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "LoadCities();" })
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Edit.SelectCityId, Model.Edit.City, "Please select", new { id = "CityID", @class = "form-control" })
```

I populate second one depending on first one and third depending on second...but when i want to display those dropdown lists for some specific user im able to display just countries

My model:

```
 public int SelectCountryId { get; set; }
 public int SelectRegionId { get; set; }
 public int SelectCityId {get; set;}
 public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList City { get; set; }
 public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList Region{ get; set; }
 public System.Web.Mvc.SelectList Country{ get; set; }
```

My controller:

```
model.Edit.SelectCountryId = user.ContactInformation.First().City.Region.Country.Id;
model.Edit.SelectRegionId = user.ContactInformation.First().City.Region.Id;
model.Edit.SelectCityId = user.ContactInformation.First().City.Id;
```

I get values on controller but i cant get display them in view

EDIT:
My scripts:

```
 var region = $('#RegionID');


    var urlCountries = "/Account/GetRegions";
    $.getJSON(urlCountries, { countryId: $('#CountryID').val() }, function (response) {
        // clear and add default (null) option

        region.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));


        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            region.append($('<option></option>').val(response[i].Id).text(response[i].Name));
        }

    });

    var city = $('#CityID');
    var url = "/Account/GetCities"; // use the helper (dont hard code)
    $.getJSON(url, { regionId: $('#RegionID').val() }, function (response) {
        // clear and add default (null) option

        city.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));

        for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            city.append($('<option></option>').val(response[i].Id).text(response[i].Name));
        }

    });
```

My methods for GetCity() and GetRegions()

```
  public IEnumerable<IRegion> GetRegions(int countryId)
        {
            Model.Administration.Region[] modelRegions = Model.Administration.Region.FindAll(DetachedCriteria.For<Model.Administration.Region>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("Country.Id", countryId)));

            return modelRegions.Select(Region.ConvertFromModel).Cast<IRegion>().ToList();
        }

  public IEnumerable<ICity> GetCities(int regionId)
        {
            CityLimited[] modelCities = CityLimited.FindAll(DetachedCriteria.For<CityLimited>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("Region.Id", regionId)));

            return modelCities.Select(City.ConvertFromModel).Cast<ICity>().ToList();
        }
```

Comment: Show your scripts for `LoadRegions()` and `LoadCities()`

Comment: The script code looks OK, but they are surrounded by the function names - `function LoadRegions() { ..}` and `function LoadCities() { ..}`

Comment: So what can i do? When i put them without function names i get sam result

Comment: Currently all you doing is calling the scripts and populating the dropdowns when the page first loads. Do you mean the dropdowns are being populated but the correct option is not being selected?

Comment: Yes..i always get "please select"

Comment: That because you are not setting the value of the select. Your controller methods need to return a second value indicating the selected value. You need to show the controller methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79386/discussion-between-none-and-stephen-muecke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass an additional value indicating the selected option in the json data your returning to the view. Your `GetRegions()` method should look like

```
public JsonResult GetRegions(int countryId) // return a JsonResult
{
    Model.Administration.Region[] modelRegions = Model.Administration.Region.FindAll(DetachedCriteria.For<Model.Administration.Region>().Add(Restrictions.Eq("Country.Id", countryId)));
    var options =  modelRegions.Select(Region.ConvertFromModel).Cast<IRegion>().ToList();
    var selection = 1; // set the value of the selected option here - must match the `ID` property of one of one of the `IRegion` your returning
    return Json(new { options = options, selection = selection }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Side note: Its not clear what `modelRegions.Select(Region.ConvertFromModel).Cast<IRegion>().ToList();` returns but if `IRegion` contains more that just the `ID` and `Name` properties you need for the view, consider creating a collection of anonymous objects so you don't send unnecessary data across the wire

Then the corresponding script should be

```
var url = '@Url.Action("GetRegions", "Account")'; // use the helper (dont hard code)
var regions = $('#RegionID'); // cache the element
$('#CountryID').change(function() {
    $.getJSON(url, { id: $(this).val() }, function(response) {
        // clear and add default (null) option
        regions.empty().append($('<option></option>').val('').text('Please select'));
        $.each(response.options, function(index, item) {
            cities.append($('<option></option>').val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
        });
        regions.val(response.selection); // set the selected value
    });
});
```

and remove the `@onchange = "LoadRegions();` from you markup

Ditto for the `GetCities()` controller method and the corresponding script